# Microsoft Flow: "send email" To multiple users email Id

Tags: power-automate

I am collecting the email in the format on for each loop:

```
First Name <FirstName@abc.com>
Second Name <SecondName@abc.com>
```

Now I wanted to send final consolidate mail to all not one by one.

For now I am using **Append to string** on for each loop concate on semicolon and passing the same into send email **TO** but it is giving me 400 Error.

I know I am wrong but tell me how to do it right way. Thanks

Comment: I think you may use [Plumsail Regex Match](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/use-regex-match-to-extract-values.html) to extract email address, but this feature requires API key and permission from administrator. Otherwise, can you post your flow structure, we may find out another way in getting emails step.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an `array()` of e-mail addresses then use it in "To" field of `Send an email` action.
The array should contain e-mail address only.

Comment: I can able to make the array like this : [First Name <FirstName@abc.com>, Second Name <SecondName@abc.com>], but i am not sure how i can get  email address only on the array like this: [ FirstName@abc.com , SecondName@abc.com ].

Comment: Please update your question and post screenshoot of your Flow. It will help to understand where does the data comes from